# What can be inferred from javascript variables that begin with _?

Tags: javascript, jquery, naming-conventions

From jquery.ui.autocomplete.js:

```
_renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
    var self = this;
    $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
        self._renderItem( ul, item );
    });
},
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Underscore prefixes in javascript are mostly used to signify "private" functions, properties etc. I.e., functions and properties that are used internally and should not be accessed from outside the library/plugin.

And yes, as nnnnnn says, the important word there is "should", as in:

- It *can* be accessed - Javascript won't do anything to stop you - it's just a naming convention.
- It would be ill-advised to actually *do* it. Mostly, the author will have good reason to indicate internal use. E.g. a property which may not behave as you think (for example cached values that won't be available in all cases); a function may depend on specific internal state or have side effects on that state; etc.

Comment: Where "should not be accessed" is the key phrase and applies to people writing code because it is a naming convention only that has no meaning to the JavaScript engine...

Answer (score 4):

Usually, people like to use _ to denote the variable/function to be private, but _ has no special meaning in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't mean anything technically but usually the writer intends it to make it as protected (internal method)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where I heard this, looking for documentation as I write this, but I believe vars that start with underscore are usually denoting a private scope.

[For reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#C_and_C.2B.2B) looks like it's a C thing that other programmers implemented.